# If $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N \times \mathbb N $ such as $f(n)=(n,n+1)$ Is it surjective and/or injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N \times \mathbb N $ such as $f(n)=(n,n+1)$ Is it surjective and/or injective?

I know that it is surjective $\Leftrightarrow \forall (a,b) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \exists c \in \mathbb N:f(c)=f(a,b)$

It is obviously injective because if $(n,n+1)=(m,m+1) \rightarrow n=m$

I can see that it is not surjective but do not know how to prove it, can I get some help?

Comment: What is $m$? Is it a  fixed integer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, my bad, it was a typo, I fixed it

Comment: +1 upvote on the question for me at least for being responsive to feedback and quickly fixing the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $(1,1)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Suppose for contradiction that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $f(n)=(n,n+1)=(1,1)$. Then reading the first entry, we get $n=1$. Reading the second entry, we get $n+1=1\implies n=0$. Clearly we can't have $n=1$ and $n=0$ at the same time. Contradiction. Hence $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: The function is not even  defined properly by OP.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, correct, but from his/her argument for injectivity you can deduce what the OP meant.